# Pass value to modal reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass value to Modal, but I unable to pass it like this:

My Modal:

```
const AmountToPayModal = (dollar: number = 0) => (
  <Container>
    <Title>
       <FormattedMessage id="creditPagePayment" />
    </Title>
    <Line />
    <SectionLabel>
       <FormattedMessage id="creditPageNoCreditRequest" />
     </SectionLabel>
     <AmountLabel>
      <span>&#36; {dollar}</span>
     </AmountLabel>
    <SupportSpan>
       <SupportLabel>
         <FormattedMessage id="creditPagePaymentQuest" />
        </SupportLabel>
     </SupportSpan>
   </Container>
);
```

And my Presenter:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as COLORS from '../../../constants/colors';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import AmountToPayModal from 
'../../../components/DataPayment/AmountToPayModal';

const Presenter = () => (
  <Container>
    <AmountToPayModal dollar={1600}/> /* Error here */
  </Container>
);

const Container = styled.div`
   background-color: ${COLORS.bgLightGrey};
`;

export default Presenter;
```

the error says:

> Type '{ dollar: 1600; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & Number'.   Type '{ dollar: 1600; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'Number'.
>       Property 'toFixed' is missing in type '{ dollar: 1600; }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>JS expressions are specified in the curly braces</strike>

```
<AmountToPayModal dollar={1600} />
```

React functional components should accept a props argument, try that:

```
export interface ModalProps {
    dollar?: number;
}

const AmountToPayModal = (props: ModalProps = { dollar: 0 }) => (
  ...
);
```

References:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Hi, still error. Please check my update error above.